# how many look up relationship in salesforce

Tags: relationships, data-model

how many lookup relationship can I create in salesforce? can you send me a link about this topic?

Comment: Create in total ? per object ? That's pretty well documented, have you looked for this yourself ?  Gelay, questions are easier to answer if we know what you've done and what you specifically mean, please try to remember that when asking questions to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create 2 master detail and 25 lookup relationship per object.